# What is best option to store list in room android

Tags: android, android-room

I have object from backend:

```
class ProductsDTO {
    @PrimaryKey
    var productId: Long = 0
    @TypeConverters(ProductConverter::class)
    var productsList: List<ProductDTO>
    var status: String

    constructor(productsList: List<ProductDTO>, status: String) {
        this.productsList = productsList
        this.status = status
    }
}
```

for now I store in database as table Products where I have 3 tables: productId, productList and status.
In future I want to use some filters to get product from `productsList` and I was wondering which would be faster: save products list to another table and search in db using query or load into memory productsList and filter by params?

Answer (score -1):

You can save the list in the database by using Converters, which is default from the Room library (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)

You have a possible example here (https://medium.com/@toddcookevt/android-room-storing-lists-of-objects-766cca57e3f9)

Hope this helps